# Laravel 7 how get parent category alias (nested-eloquent)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 7 how get parent category `alias`?

I have got two tables:

```
        Schema::create('blog_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
            $table->string('alias')->unique();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('alias')->unique();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('fragment')->nullable();
            $table->text('content_html');

            $table->boolean('is_published')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories');
            $table->index('is_published');
        });
```

In Models:

```
class BlogPost extends Model
{

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class);
    }

    public function parentCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class,
            'id', 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

```
class BlogCategory extends Model
{
     public function parentCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class,
            'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And the route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Blog', 'prefix' => 'blog'], function () {
    Route::get('posts', 'BlogPostController@index')->name('blog.posts');
    Route::get('{parentCategory}{category}/{alias}', 'BlogPostController@showPost')->name('user.blog.showPost');
});
```

In controller I have the following method:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $getAllWithPaginate = $this->blogPostRepository->getAllWithPaginate();

        return view('blog', compact('getAllWithPaginate'));
    }
```

In the view I can access the `$item->category->alias` and `$item->alias`, but how can I access to the parent category alias?

```
    @foreach ($getAllWithPaginate as $item)
       <a href="{{ route('user.blog.showPost', [**question here (how get parent category alias?)**, $item->category->alias, $item->alias]) }}" class="for-posts-link">
    @enforeach
```

Something like this `parentCategory->alias` parameter in route? Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is at the eloquent naming convention, there are two ways you can do this.
1) Create eloquent attribute
2) Create eloquent relationship(which you did,but can be improved with more convention way of doing it.) 
Below is a sample of how I would do it.

```
class BlogCategory extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class,'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and in the view I would access it like.

```
  {{ $item->category->parent->alias }}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! It's work! I didn't know I could do this ```{{ $item->category->parent->alias }}```